# Getting List of Record Types and Looking up Values

Tags: lightning-web-components, record-type

I have a wire that gets the object information for a custom object.  I was then setting a variable for record type for a specific record type.  I am expanding my component where I will need to lookup multiple record types from the object.  Here is the wire I am using now.  I could simply add else statements to assign the record type id to different variables.  I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this.  This LWC will only be used for one record (with one record type) at a time.  But it will be used for records with different record types.  Hope that makes sense.  thanks!

```
    // Get record types for Opportunity products
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OPPPROD_OBJECT})    
getObjectInfo({ error, data }) {     
    if (data) {
        this.lstRecordTypes = [];
        for (let key in data.recordTypeInfos) {
            this.lstRecordTypes.push({ value: key, label:data.recordTypeInfos[key].name});
        }
        this.lstRecordTypes.forEach(rec => {
          if(rec.label === 'Health'){
            this.recordType = rec.value;
          }
          //could add else if statement here and assigne to different variable
        })

    }

    else if (error) {
        console.log('Error while get record types');
        this.lstRecordTypes = [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach would be creating a map of `record type labels to their IDs`. This way, you can easily look up the `record type ID` for any given label without having to iterate over the list each time.

With the following you can easily find the record type ID for any label:

```
let recordTypeId = this.recordTypeMap.get('Health');




 // Get record types for Opportunity products
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OPPPROD_OBJECT })    
    getObjectInfo({ error, data }) {     
        if (data) {
            this.recordTypeMap = new Map();
            for (let key in data.recordTypeInfos) {
                let recordTypeInfo = data.recordTypeInfos[key];
                this.recordTypeMap.set(recordTypeInfo.name, key);
            }
        } else if (error) {
            console.log('Error while getting record types');
        }
    }
```